# Saving the site as a template does not retain navigation settings in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I followed the [link](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/10/05/save-publishing-site-as-a-template/) to save site as template and restore it.

After restore, I found that left navigation setting (Page names and their ordering) was not there in restored site.

I searched about it and found that is was not available in SP 2010. Ref [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2716884/saving-the-site-as-a-template-does-not-retain-navigation-settings)

I want to know if this is possible in Sharepoint online to backup and import left navigation links to new site? Currently, when I restore the site, left navigation links do not retain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in SharePoint Online. The difference is you need to go to Site Settings and click Navigation under Look and Feel to manually the navigation settings based on your requirement.